# Generate random shades of green

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, generator

I'm tying to do a generator of shades of green, the problem is... the green can't be too much dark nor too much bright. I made/tried the bellow code, but I can't seen to find a way to avoid almost black green and almost white green.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var a = Math.random() * 254;
        var b = Math.floor(a / 8) * 8;
        $(".greybox").css("background-color", "rgb(0," + b + ",0)");
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.greybox {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="greybox">this is grey box</div>
```

Comment: don't use 254 - use something smaller and add a base value.

Comment: @DanielA.White I tried to find a "number" on google ... no luck here =(

Comment: its what you want to make of it. *experiment*

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm doing it =D but while trying, I'm asking. Maybe someone already found my ["42"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_number_42)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a random range for what your need.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var max = 150;
        var min = 100;
        var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        $(".greybox").css("background-color", "rgb(0," + green + ",0)");
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: I was trying something similar =) the range that I liked was 50 ~ 254 but I think it may change (need to see the feedback of my manager) thanks =)

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = (Math.random() * 125) + 100;
```

this will give you random colours starting with a dark green and going up to bright green. No black.

If you don't want really bright green:

```
var a = (Math.random() * 90) + 100;
```

change the range as you feel fit.